# Same value filled on a field based on another field

Tags: fields

As an example : [image: for ref]

While creating a new user we observe that the username field on the user object fills in same as the email field on pressing TAB button, I would like to know how this functionality is being achieved !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Username by default is the same as the User's email address. It's standard Salesforce functionality where they copy the value of the email field automatically to the Username field for you in the background. In other words, this is what's expected and working as intended. To replicate it, you'd need to use Javascript or some other ajax method related to "onfocus".